# Can't create new Solr core caused by can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'

Tags: solr

I just installed Solr and want to create a new core, but getting this error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/var/solr/data/new_core'
```

I was trying to add it using the interface:

[image]

I hope somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 8):

The option to create a new core in the Admin web page that you are using is a bit misleading, that option assumes you already have folders with some of the required data.

If you have access to the terminal on the machine where Solr is running you can easily create a core with a command like this:

```
$ cd ~/solr-8.4.1/bin
$ ./solr create -c name-of-your-new-core
```