# Error CREATEing SolrCore: Unable to create core Caused by: /var/solr/data/searchfin/data/snapshot_metadata

Tags: solr

I am trying to add a new solr core but it's giving me the following error:

**Error CREATEing SolrCore 'searchfin': Unable to create core [searchfin] Caused by: /var/solr/data/searchfin/data/snapshot_metadata**

I have already created the folder "searchfin" with subfolder conf and data in it. Also I have tried creating the core with both solr UI and command line.

Comment: The option in the Solr Admin UI is (mostly) useless. The command line is usually a good approach. What command did you use to create it via the command line? Was is something like indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591065/446681

Comment: I have used the following command:
./solr create -c searchfin

And yes, I ran this command in bin directory.